# Setting correct content type for cURL to receive a response

Tags: php, curl, api-design

I'm trying to create a relatively simple PHP endpoint for users to send requests to. I know that the endpoint is working because when I accessed it using cURL the parameters I sent to my database we're added. The problem however is that when I use

```
 var_dump($response);
```

The page returns "NULL".

So the code is working fine, I just want to know how to print an error/success message

This is what I've tried so far on the endpoint

```
header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK"); 
header('Content-Type: text/plain'); 
echo 'Success message';
```

the full cURL code:

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_URL => $url,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => 'example=this'
);
$resp = curl_exec($curl);
// Close request to clear up some resources
curl_close($curl);
$response = json_decode($resp, true);
var_dump($response);
```

So how can I get the success message to properly show instead of "NULL"?

Comment: Why are you calling json_decode on content that is not JSON? _That’s_ why you are getting NULL. Do a var_dump of $resp instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Test if your curl code returns something by testing: `var_dump($resp)`. It looks like  `NULL` comes from `json_decode`. You are not returning valid JSON from the endpoint.

```
php > var_dump(json_decode("Success message", true));
NULL
```

Try returning a json string such as:

```
php > echo json_encode("Success", true);
"Success"
```

Note the `"` around it. This encodes a json string. See the [JSON spec](http://www.json.org/) for a reference on how to encode json. Best practice, if your return json, then run your content through `json_encode()`.

Your curl code seems correct.

Comment: Your right, the JSON wasn't valid. Working perfectly now, thank you very much for your help.